# Using ffmpeg and ffplay piped together in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, pipeline

I have switched my current video project from command prompt to PowerShell so that I can take full advantage of the `Tee-Object` for a multi output code.

Currently, I have a version of my code working in batch, but I need to add one more feature through a tee. This is my first time using PowerShell, so this is probably a simple fix...

Currently I have figured out how to run `ffmpeg` and `ffplay` in PowerShell, and I have a program in batch which takes an `ffmpeg` output and pipes it to `ffplay`, and this works just fine. I can also play through `ffplay` in PS just fine. In PS, this code works:

```
ffplay -video_size 1280x720 -pixel_format uyvy422 -framerate 60 -i video="Decklink Video Capture"
```

And as a batch, this code works fine for what I'm doing:

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1280x720 -pixel_format uyvy422 -framerate 60 -i video="Decklink Video Capture" -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -mpegts pipe: | ffplay pipe:
```

It takes the video I want and plays it through the pipe to the screen. When played through PowerShell, though, the video doesn't even pop up. I don't get any warnings or anything, and it seems to run fine, but I don't get the picture to display.

End goal is to be able to play the video on the host display in full resolution, and publish a lower bitrate to the network, if that helps.

Comment: Toss `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` before your `ff` calls to see if something's being thrown but not displayed.

Comment: I went ahead and did this, and the program immediately stopped. I take it there's a deeper issue then?

Comment: Yeah, that&#39;s an error being forced to terminate.  Wrap the call in a try/catch block and put `$_ | Format-List * -Force; Pause` in the catch block to see the error record

Comment: So I went ahead and did this, and didn't get anything new. I can see things running as it goes, but nothing stops for an error, and I haven't had any light shed on what's going on...

Answer (score 5):

The reason you are seeing strange behavior, is that piping in PowerShell does not work the same way as in the old cmd-interpreter/console. Basically it is parsed by PowerShell before being passed on to the next command.
You may read more in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1908) about some of the ongoing work to enable two native processes to pass raw byte-streams in PowerShell.

If you are unable to just run your command in a legacy cmd-shell (it would probably be the easiest way), you may use the module [Use-RawPipeline](https://github.com/GeeLaw/PowerShellThingies/tree/master/modules/Use-RawPipeline).

```
Install-Module -Name Use-RawPipeline
```

Then you can construct a command line like this (I've simplified the argument list to just to use a file and skip the decklink-source for brevity):

```
Invoke-NativeCommand -FilePath .\ffmpeg -ArgumentList @("-i", "C:\temp\testfile.mp4","-f","h264", "pipe:") |
Invoke-NativeCommand -FilePath .\ffplay.exe -ArgumentList @("pipe:") |
Receive-RawPipeline
```

If you need to add more command to the pipeline, just insert another `Invoke-NativeCommand -FilePath <command>` before the `Receive-RawPipeline`.

Note: I am not sure about the performance of this solution, but I have confirmed it will pipe the output of ffmpeg to ffplay and display the encoded stream.

Answer (score 1):

Example that pipes from ffmpeg to x265:

```
$env:ffmpeg = 'D:\ffmpeg.exe'
$env:x265   = 'D:\x265.exe'
$env:avs    = 'D:\test.avs'
$env:output = 'D:\test.hevc'

$env:ffmpeg_args = '-f yuv4mpegpipe -strict -1 -loglevel fatal -hide_banner'

$env:x265_args = '--crf 18 --output-depth 10 --y4m'

cmd /s /c --% ""%ffmpeg%" -i "%avs%" %ffmpeg_args% - | "%x265%" %x265_args% --output "%output%" -"
```

In short:

```
cmd /s /c --% "<cmd style command>"
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer because it shows how to pass variables created in the script in the CMD command. Saved me a lot of time!